# javascript/php - shorten string to fit into a certain # of lines

Tags: javascript, php, string, ellipsis

I have a string that must fit into a box, and must be at most 3 lines long. To shorten it, I plan to truncate it and end it with '...'. I could shorten it to a certain # of characters but if i make it look good with "wwwwwwwww [...] wwww" it won't look right with "iiiiiiiiiii [...] iiii".

Is there some way I can shorten it by how much space the string would take up, as opposed to how many characters there are in a string without using a fixed-width font? Ideally I'd like to do this server-side (php) but recognize that actual character width stuff is far more likely to be feasible client-side (JS / jQuery)

Mala

ps. Please no "simply create an image of '...' and overlay it over the end of the line" hacks or similar - I actually want to shorten the string to the appropriate length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [imageftbbox](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageftbbox.php) and [imagettfbbox](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) for that.

Comment: very interesting solution - this would even work server-side :) Is this function quick though? I'm looking at having to do this 200+ times per page

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-how-to-auto-ellipse-text

Comment: This seems like the ideal JS solution - I'm still hoping for a quick server-side way, but barring that I'll probably end up going with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/measuring-the-length-of-a-string-in-pixels-using-javascript/) offers as good a way as any, and is cross-browser. I like the simplicity:

Comment: This seems pretty much identical to lazerscience's solution - excellent find though, thanks :)

Comment: @Mala: There weren't any solutions when I posted. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I can think of to easily get font sizes to the degree that you speak of, but there may be a hack that would "appear" the way you want.  I assume since you mention three lines, we're talking about a `<textarea>` element:

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="50" style="overflow:hidden;"></textarea>
```

Although the text is there, it's not visible and the scroll bars would not display.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of jQuery plugins for this: http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/2229